# Object Mapping with RestKit to CoreData

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

This code:

```
NSString* MIMEType = @"application/xml";
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:MIMEType];

NSError* error = nil;
NSString* XMLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:myLocallyStoredFileName ofType:@"xml"]
                                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                   error:nil];
NSData* XMLData = [XMLString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id parsedData = [RKMIMETypeSerialization objectFromData:XMLData MIMEType:MIMEType error:&error];
if (parsedData == nil && error) {
    // Parser error...
}

RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[myCoreDataObject class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                             ... my mappings ...
                                                     }];

NSDictionary *mappingsDictionary = @{ [NSNull null]: mapping };
RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedData mappingsDictionary:mappingsDictionary];
NSError *mappingError = nil;


NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = ((MPTAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).persistentStoreCoordinator;
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache *cache = [RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache new];

RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource *source =
[[RKManagedObjectMappingOperationDataSource alloc]
 initWithManagedObjectContext:context
 cache:cache];

mapper.mappingOperationDataSource = source;
BOOL isMapped = [mapper execute:&mappingError];
if (isMapped && !mappingError) {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
```

Gives me the following error:

> CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'myCoreDataObject'

It is as if the mapping operation does not know I am using Core Data. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

That's because your mapping is an instance of `RKObjectMapping` where it should be an instance of `RKEntityMapping` to integrate properly with Core Data. When you create the mapping, you then supply the Core Data entity rather than the representative Class.

---

Also, you should really let RestKit manage the Core Data stack for you. To do that, create the stack something like:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

NSError *error;
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"XXXX.sqlite"];

NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
```

Then you have a fully configured `managedObjectStore` to use.

(As it stands at the moment you don't have a `managedObjectStore`, so from the code in your comment you're just passing `nil`).

Comment: I made the following change:     RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"myCoreDataObject" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore]; but now I get: Invalid parameter not satisfying: managedObjectStore